# how to get source code syntax working in the maven-fluido-skin maven site skin?

Tags: apache, maven, apt

The bootstrap based maven-fluido-skin skin is eye candy but I cannot figure out how to get source code to render within the apt pages. Does anyone have an example of how to put an xml or java code snippet into the source apt so that it renders as syntax highlighted in the output html page?

Comment: Do you mean something on this page: http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-daemon-jvmsettings.html

Comment: yes. what does the source look like for that page?

Comment: found it https://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/mojo/tags/appassembler-1.2.2/appassembler-maven-plugin/src/site/apt/usage-daemon-jvmsettings.apt.vm?r=16499

Comment: thanks khmarbasie that renders stuff great. is there a away to have it add line numbers to the java code?

Comment: using awk to add line numbers with awk '{printf("%5d : %s\n", NR,$0)}' input > output which is fine for java but for xml you have have to not number the first line for it to recognise things as being xml to syntax highlight it okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate the line numbers by an option for the fluido skin:

```
<project name="xxx">
  [...]
  <custom>
    <fluidoSkin>
      <sourceLineNumbersEnabled>true</sourceLineNumbersEnabled>
    </fluidoSkin>
  </custom>
  [...]
</project>
```

This is an excerpt of the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/skins/maven-fluido-skin/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Khmarbaise. I actually did not know to put the "+-----" markers in the apt which I got from the link to your code you gave me in your comment to my question I have edited your answer to expand on it a little with that fact. Hopefully my edits will be visible in short while when it is moderated.